# Time series Python Plot (Axes mismatch)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have created a Pandas Dataframe and converted the 'date' column into a time series object using the pd.to_datetime function. I have attempted to plot out the associated plots both in Python and Excel to see if the time-stamps map appropriately.

The first plot is an Excel Plot with Times mapped against the points.
I have attempted to replicate this in Python - with just the 'observations', the plot mirrors the Excel Plot. However as soon as I add in the 'dates', the plot becomes a spaghetti plot.

I can't seem to work out why this is the case - can anyone advise?

I used the following line on my date field:

```
CNN006['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(CNN006['Date'])
```

This correctly converted the date to a time stamp (picture 4)

Please refer to the attached:
[image: Excel TS Plot]

[image: Python Plot with no dates]

[image: Python Plot with dates]

[image: Date Conversion Successful]

The link to the csv file is here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kctGhXafHYXxC1rSFvdwgvmvLAo2RLsZ

***EDIT - I have tried another approach which is modifying the xticks but this has had mixed results and not given me what I want***

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
myFmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

**EDIT
This is the code for plots 2 and 3 respectively
**Plot 2**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.grid()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.plot(CNN006.Date,CNN006.DailyAvgGasFlowRate)
ax.plot(CNN006.Date,CNN006.DailyAvgWaterRate)
ax.plot(CNN006.Date, CNN006.DailyAvgTorque)
```

*Plot 3

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.grid()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.plot(CNN006.DailyAvgGasFlowRate)
ax.plot(CNN006.DailyAvgWaterRate)
ax.plot(CNN006.DailyAvgTorque)
```

**SOLUTION**

```
CNN006['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(CNN006['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
ax = CNN006.set_index('Date').plot()
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

I had previously assumed with the .to_date functionality, it would automatically convert the date string to the appropriate time series without explicitly requiring formatting to be passed in. I realise now that this is not the case, we have to specify the format in the .to_date function so that MatPlotLib doesn't get confused with the incoming dates not matching the user-specified 'date' manipulation (i.e. xmft in my code). 
[image: Solution_for_Plot]

Comment: Could you please post the codes that you used to plot Figures 2 and 3?

Comment: @ThomasKühn - I have updated the question with my Code. Thank you.

Comment: Since `to_datetime()` was not provided a format string, the date parser made assumptions about the format.  Specifically, it tried 'MM/DD/YYYY', and if that failed it tried 'DD/MM/YYYY'.  So, the first three rows in the resulting dataframes had `Date` "November 1, 2016; December 1, 2016; January 13, 2016".  Matplotlib plotted these in the order of the Dataframe, and connected the lines (so the third datapoint appeared to jump back in time --- hence the "spaghetti").  The call to Matplotlib's `set_major_formatter` only controls how the dates are printed on the xaxis, which, was done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with the date format of your data.  If you provide a format string to `to_datetime()`, you should be all set.

```
df = pd.read_csv('MatplotLibTSManipulation.csv')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
ax = df.set_index('Date').plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated my answer which built on what you had provided. I expected how my data was parsed in pandas would automatically have the specified data format applied, but this wasn't the case. We have to manually specify the format type before it will work.